# why isn't my code not working without this part

Tags: python

In this quick sort algorithm although I have specified my list above which has some elements, when running without the length <= 1 its showing the given error. Why is it so can somebody explain?

this is the code-

```
lst = [5,3,8,6,7,2]

def quick_sort(lst):
    length = len(lst)
    if length <= 1:
        return lst
    else:
        a = lst.pop()

    grt_lst = []
    sml_lst = []

    for i in lst:
        if i > a:
            grt_lst.append(i)
        else:
            sml_lst.append(i)

    return quick_sort(sml_lst) + [a] + quick_sort(grt_lst)

print(quick_sort(lst))
```

this is the error -

```
File "c:\Users\dueth\OneDrive\Documents\vs code\main.py", line 45, in quick_sort
    a = lst.pop()
        ^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Comment: Any information important to your question should be in the question body itself rather than being posted separately as a comment. Please [edit] and add that to your question.

Comment: Well as the error says you can't pop a item from an empty list, take a look at a [list.pop doc](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop). That's why there is the `length <= 1` thing it checks if the list has no iems anymore to stop that error from happening and from running indefinitely

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? As the error says the issue is with empty lists and the code you remove guards against that - why are you wondering that removing the safety leads to unsafe behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

An empty list or a list with one element is sorted. There's no need to go further. When dealing with recursion we always need this type of exit condition or "base case" which the function's recursive calls converge on.

Without this, we eventually ask the function to pop from an empty list and the error you saw is encountered.

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.pop()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Without that check, your function will eventually call itself recursively on an empty list, and it will try to pop from an empty list.

Without the check:

```
quick_sort([5,3,8,6,7,2])
  a: 2
  sml_lst: []
  grt_lst: [5, 3, 8, 6, 7]

  quick_sort([])
    ERROR!
```

With the check:

```
quick_sort([5,3,8,6,7,2])
  a: 2
  sml_lst: []
  grt_lst: [5, 3, 8, 6, 7]

  quick_sort([]) -> []

  quick_sort([5, 3, 8, 6, 7])
    a: 7
    sml_lst: [5, 3, 6]
    grt_lst: [8]

    quick_sort([5, 3, 6])
      a: 6
      sml_lst: [5, 3]
      grt_lst: []
  
      quick_sort([5, 3])
        a: 3
        sml_lst: []
        grt_lst: [5]

        quick_sort([]) -> []
        quick_sort([5]) -> [5]

        [] + [3] + [5] -> [3, 5]

      quick_sort([]) -> []

      [3, 5] + [6] + [] -> [3, 5, 6]

    quick_sort([8]) -> [8]

    [3, 5, 6] + [7] + [8] -> [3, 5, 6, 7, 8]

  [] + [2] + [3, 5, 6, 7, 8] -> [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

However, you could simply check if the list is empty and return it in that case, thus terminating the recursion.

```
def quick_sort(lst):
  if lst == []: return lst

  a = lst[0]

  lt, gt = [], []

  for x in lst[1:]:
    if x < a: lt.append(x)
    elif x > a: gt.append(x)

  return quick_sort(lt) + [a] + quick_sort(gt)
```

Note also that by not using `pop`, we don't damage the initial list.